# TypeError: Invalid URL: undefined/auth/v1, js engine: hermes

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo, supabase

I am using react-native with expo and trying to connect supabase.
This is my code:

lib/supabase.ts

```
import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto'
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store'
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'

const ExpoSecureStoreAdapter = {
  getItem: (key: string) => {
    return SecureStore.getItemAsync(key)
  },
  setItem: (key: string, value: string) => {
    SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, value)
  },
  removeItem: (key: string) => {
    SecureStore.deleteItemAsync(key)
  },
}

const supabaseUrl = String(process.env.SUPABASE_URL)
const supabaseAnonKey = String(process.env.SUPABASE_KEY)

export const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey, {
  auth: {
    storage: ExpoSecureStoreAdapter as any,
    autoRefreshToken: true,
    persistSession: true,
    detectSessionInUrl: false
  },
})
```

[This is exactly what supabase provides](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-expo)

[image: I end up getting the following errors:]

I dont know why i am getting this errors I have tried clearing the cache reinstalling node modules I have checked that I am using the correct Keys.

Comment: Did you add your Supabase URL and API KEY in the .env file?

Comment: Yes I did add them both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten to set up dotenv for react-native.